# Using mathematical induction?

Tags: inequality, induction

Use mathematical induction to prove the following statement:

For all $b\in\mathbb R$, and for all $n\in\mathbb N$, $$b>-1\implies (1+b)^n \geq 1+nb$$

When $n=1$, the inequality still holds
$1+b \geq 1+b$.

For n+1$:
$$(1+b)^{n+1} \geq 1+(n+1)b$$
Here I'm not sure the best way to simplify...
$$(1+b)^n(1+b)\geq 1+bn+b$$

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Comment: How do you format questions?  People fix mine but I'd like to post them right in the first place..

Comment: See this site for hints about nice formatting: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: For help on notation, see http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 2):

$$(1+b)^{n+1} =(1+b)^n (1+b) \geq (1+nb)(1+b) =1+(n+1)b +nb^2 \geq 1+ (n+1)b.$$

Answer (score 2):

A few points:

- The base case, in this case, is $n=0,$ so that's what you should verify, not $n=1.$
- $$\color{green}{(1+b)^{n+1}} \equiv \underbrace{(1+b)^n(1+b) \geq (1+bn)(1+b)}_{\text{induction hypothesis}} \equiv 1+(n+1)b+\underbrace{b^2n}_{\geq 0} \color{green}{\geq 1+(n+1)b} .$$
- Never say something like "let $n=n+1$". It makes no sense, algebraically. You can say that if the result is true for $n$, then it's true for $n+1$, **or** you can say "if the result is true for $n=k$, then it's true for $n=k+1.$"

Comment: How is the base case n=0? I'm confused I thought 0 was not a natural number.

Comment: You want to prove it for all integers $n>-1.$ The smallest integer greater than $-1$ is $0.$

Answer (score 1):

For the induction step, if $(1+b)^n\geq 1+bn$, then
$$
(1+b)^{n+1}-(1+b(n+1))\geq (1+b)(1+bn)-(1+b(n+1))=b^2n\geq 0.
$$
Note that the first inequality above uses both the induction hypothesis and $b>-1$.